# Git : Silently changing user name and carrying on as normal 

Tags: git

Hi guys : I develop on a VM sometimes, for my company.  The git account on my VM was belonging to an accoutn which is now not on our github users  anymore.  Thus, I cannot commit my recent changes or do a pull.

Git simply sais :

Permission to XXXXXXXX denied to johndoe

Anyways ... How can I update git to use MY credentials, rather than johndoe's, now that johndoe is not in the company ?

*Of course, the odd thing here - is the fact that git is pushing as johndoe -I always thought that my git was working normally, as jayunit100.  This may in and of itself be an issue, but for now, I dont care --- I just want to swap in my correct git credentials so that I can pull, push, and get on with my life.*

Comment: Have you created a new ssh key and associated it with your account on Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to be sure which login you use to push/pull with your [remote](http://gitmanual.org/git-remote.html), for example from on of my projects:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@projects.ceondo.com:photon.git (fetch)
origin  git@projects.ceondo.com:photon.git (push)
```

The user is `git`, in your case, it was `johndoes@yourcompany.com:repo.git` and you want `jayunit100@yourcompany.com:repo.git`, so you simply need to change the definition of the remote:

```
$ cat .git/config
... skip ...
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@projects.ceondo.com:photon.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Edit the url line with your new user. Then run `git remote -v` again. You will see something like:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  foo@projects.ceondo.com:photon.git (fetch)
origin  foo@projects.ceondo.com:photon.git (push)
```

You can now pull/push as usual, it has changed only the way you access the repository, so life goes on.

Comment: This is an EXCELLENT answer.  I wish I could double upvote.  You just saved my life.  By changing the URL in that .git/config to the "correct" one, I was able to get it working !

Answer (score 1):

In my limited experience with Git, it has always asked for credentials except when using an ssh key. Do you simply need to (backup and) remove the ssh key and make a new one tied with your account?

Answer (score 1):

Set git user info like this:

```
$ git config --global user.name "My Name"
$ git config --global user.email "My Email"
```

As for github credentials, that's controlled by your SSH key.

Comment: How can i test, specifically, if git user = git ssh credentials ?

Comment: Well you have a github login, and it has a username and email (which you should already know I assume). You can compare those to the output of `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.gmail` Now look in your account settings on github, at the SSH keys, one should match the content of ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub